# How to fix FDISK_partition scheme after repartitioning a larger space for bootcamp

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, partition, recovery, guid

[image]

I have a Mac that is running Mojave, and yesterday I was trying to repartition the disk so I could get more space on my Windows partition for bootcamp.

In the process, the Windows folder only appeared for me to boot up. So I decided to install gdisk. In the process, I specified h for hybrid recovery command and used 2, 3, 4 for GPT partition numbers. When it asked to specify a hex code, I used ac for partition 2, 07 for partition 3, and 07 for partition 4. I then told it to set the bootable flag for partition 3. It then asked me if I wanted to change partition 4 to EE so I said yes. I have data on partition 2 I would like to recover, if that is still possible.

Now, I cannot boot into either Mac or Windows. And the ability to use gdisk has disappeared. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, having Mojave and a BIOS booting Windows is an uncommon, but possible combination. So I have to ask: Are you sure your Mac is setup this way?

The first partition should be type EE. When the `gdisk` command asks something like "good for grub?" The answer should be Yes. This will set the first partition to type `EE`. The second partition usually is where macOS resides. If you have Mojave installed, then this will be an APFS container. **There is no hex code for a APFS type of partition.** Feel free to make one up. How about `FF`? If the Mac is using a APFS container, then the third partition will be for Windows. This should be type `07` and should be marked as bootable. You can use the `P` command in `gdisk` to see what is in the GPT. This should confirm what I have posted so far. The 4th partition can be left empty.

> Of course, if Windows is UEFI booting, then all of the above can be ignored. In this case, you want a fully protected MBR table.

You do not include much information on how exactly you managed to repartition a larger space for Boot Camp. I doubt this can be accomplished by using `gdisk` alone.

I see from your post, that you can boot to macOS Recovery. Try to capture the output from the following commands and post to your question. Note: With the current state of the partition tables, the `gpt` command may produce an error message..

```
fdisk /dev/disk0
gpt -r show /dev/disk0
```

Next, type typing the following commands.

```
fdisk -e /dev/disk0
set 4
07
quit
```

If asked about writing out, confirm you want to.

Hopefully, you will be able to boot macOS.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned at my Windows partition is not BIOS booting. I don't have the ability to access gdisk anymore, is there a way to install it if I have no bootable disks? When I turn on my Mac it has the flashing circle with a line through it. I had repartitioned the disk originally through disk utility and added two empty EX Fat partitions

Comment: Hold on, I am updating the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to boot into Mac OS!